# Sort an array in the relative order of elements of another array in c

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I wish to sort a second array as per the first array. e.g.

```
first = {1,8,7,2,4}
second = {9,7,2,10,3}
```

I want first to be unchanged and second to be sorted in the same relative order as the first.  i.e.  the lowest value is at index 0, the second lowest value is at index 3, third lowest value is at index 4 etc etc

```
second = {2,10,9,3,7}
```

I have already tried some code for the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int num;
    int pos;
}ArrType;

ArrType arrA[5] = {{1,0},{8,1},{7,2},{2,3},{4,4}};
ArrType arrB[5] = {{9,0},{7,1},{2,2},{10,3},{3,4}};;

int cmparr(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    ArrType *tmpa, *tmpb;
    tmpa = (ArrType*) a;
    tmpb = (ArrType*) b;

    return(arrA[tmpa->pos].num - arrA[tmpb->pos].num);
}
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    qsort(arrB,5, sizeof(ArrType), cmparr);

    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf ("%d ",arrB[i].num);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

The actual output is

> 9 10 3 2 7

I am open to a different data structure, but `arrB` should only be sorted one time.

I have seen some solutions for this in C++, Javascipt and other languages. But there is not a solution in C.

Edit - These arrays would be quite large in the final program. I am looking for a single sorting operation. i.e. single call to `qsort`

Comment: The actual output is not as expected. Something is wrong in the `cmparr` function or in the data structures used.

Comment: @Socowi - I have specified the expected output `second = {2,10,9,3,7}`

Comment: @Socowi i believe it is more like: you check the order of `first` so lowest is at position 0 next is at position 3 etc. Then you apply this order to `second` so you search the lowest value and place it at position 0 then you search the next value and place it at position 3 etc.

Comment: @Socowi sry now i understand your comment and youre right

Comment: @Yastanub Thank you for your input. I think I was wrong and you understood OP correctly in your first comment. After all OP wrote »*the second lowest value is at index 3*« where index 3 is the initial position of the second lowest entry in `first`.

Comment: @Tibrogargan With `<kbd>` and `</kbd>`. (Hint: If you want to learn tricks of formatting from other Q/As, just press [edit] and look into the source code. In SO, every Q/A is open source. I learnt most tricks that way...) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff yep - thought of that after you deleted it :D

Comment: @Ranon You're not going to find a solution with a single sorting operation.  Since you implicitly need to be able to answer the question "what element is the largest element in an array?" you either need to sort both of them or search them - a much more expensive operation on an unsorted array.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the meta-data that matches the desired ordering (i.e  an array of indexes).  Then apply that meta-data to the second array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int first[] = {1,8,7,2,4};
int second[] = {9,7,2,10,3};

int compare(const void * a, const void * b);
int binary_search(int array[], int min, int max, int target);
void print_array(int * array, int c);

int main()
{
  int idx;
  int c = sizeof(first)/sizeof(int);
  int * sorted = NULL;
  int * indexes = NULL;
  int * result = NULL;

  if (NULL == (sorted = malloc(sizeof(first)))) {
      return -1;
  }
  memcpy(sorted, first, sizeof(first));

  if (NULL == (indexes = malloc(sizeof(first)))) {
      free(sorted);
      return -1;
  }
  memset(indexes, -1, sizeof(first));

  if (NULL == (result = malloc(sizeof(second)))) {
      free(sorted);
      free(indexes);
      return -1;
  }
  memset(result, -1, sizeof(second));

  // 1st: Sort the reference array
  qsort (sorted, c, sizeof(int), compare);

  // 2nd: Record the position of each sorted element in the original array (this is your meta-data)
  for (idx=0; idx<c; idx++) {
      indexes[idx] = binary_search(sorted, 0, c, first[idx]);
  }

  // 3rd sort the target array
  memcpy(sorted, second, sizeof(second));
  qsort (sorted, c, sizeof(int), compare);

  // 4th apply the stored positions to the sorted target array
  for (idx = 0; idx < c; idx++) {
      result[idx] = sorted[indexes[idx]];
  }
  print_array(result, c);

  free(result);
  free(indexes);
  free(sorted);
  return 0;
}

int compare(const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

int binary_search(int array[], int min, int max, int target)
{
    int mid;
    while (min <= max)
    {
        mid = min + (max - min)/2;
        if (target > array[mid])
            min = mid + 1;
        else if (target < array[mid])
            max = mid - 1;
        else
            return mid;
    }
    return -1;
}

void print_array(int * array, int c)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    } 
    printf("\n");
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a6aabfd19914c39e)

Comment: There are 3 sorting operations in this solution. As the size of the array would be large, i am looking for a single sort operation.

Comment: Where is the 3rd?  Not that it matters, 2 is greater than 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach, it uses qsort twice and arrC contains the result.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{   
    int num;
    int pos;
}ArrType;

ArrType arrA[5] = {{1,0},{8,1},{7,2},{2,3},{4,4}};
int arrB[5] = {9,7,2,10,3};;
int arrC[5];
int cmpInt(const void *a, const void *b)
{   
        return(*a - *b);
}
int cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{   
    ArrType *tmpa, *tmpb;
    tmpa = (ArrType*) a;
    tmpb = (ArrType*) b; 
        return(tmpa->num - tmpb->num);
}
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    qsort(arrA,5, sizeof(ArrType), cmp);
    qsort(arrB,5, sizeof(ArrType), cmpInt);
    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {   
        arrC[arrA[i].pos] = arrB[i];
    }   
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: There are 2 sorting operations here. Can it be done with only a single sorting operation?

Comment: @Ranon We need to find the mapping of sorted vs given order, it will require one sorting procedure. Other sorting procedure is for getting second array sorted so that using the mapping is a linear operation. This is a NlogN solution, if we manage to do it in a single sorting operation it will still be NlogN.

Answer (score 0):

Since C doesn't have a lambda compare (which could be used to sort an array of indexes according to first[]), the code below sorts an array of pointers ap[] to the elements of first[] using qsort(). Using pointers eliminates the need to pass an array name as a parameter for the compare function, which in turn allows the compare function to work with qsort(). The expression (ap[i]-first) converts a pointer into an index. Next second[] is sorted, also using qsort(). Then ap[] is used as a set of ranks to reorder second[] in place and in O(n) time.

To explain reorder by rank versus reorder by index:

```
    dst[rank[i]] = src[i];              /* reorder by rank */
    dst[i] = src[index[i]];             /* reorder by index */
```

Example code:

```
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* compare for ptr to integer */
int cmppi(const void *p0, const void *p1){
    return (*(int *)p0 - *(int *)p1);
}

/* compare for ptr to ptr to integer */
int cmpppi(const void *p0, const void *p1){
    return (**(int **)p0 - **(int **)p1);
}

int main()
{
int first[] =  {1, 8, 7, 2, 4};
int second[] = {9, 7, 2,10, 3};
int **ap;                               /* array of pointers */
int *tmpp;
int tmpi;
size_t i, j;

    /* allocate and generate array of pointers to first[] */
    ap = (int **)malloc(sizeof(first)/sizeof(first[0])*sizeof(int *));
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(first)/sizeof(first[0]); i++)
        ap[i] = &first[i];
    /* sort ap  */
    qsort(ap, sizeof(first)/sizeof(first[0]), sizeof(int *), cmpppi);
    /* sort second */
    qsort(second, sizeof(second)/sizeof(second[0]), sizeof(int), cmppi);
    /* reorder ap and second in place using ap as rank (O(n) time) */
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(second) / sizeof(second[0]); i++){
        while(i != (j = ap[i] - first)){
            tmpp = ap[i];               /* swap(ap[i], ap[j]) */
            ap[i] = ap[j];
            ap[j] = tmpp;
            tmpi = second[i];           /* swap(second[i], second[j] */
            second[i] = second[j];
            second[j] = tmpi;
        }
    }   
    /* display second[] */
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(second) / sizeof(second[0]); i++)
        printf("%3d", second[i]);
    printf("\n");
    free(ap);
    return 0;
}
```